# ¿Como obtener coordenadas de la mi ubicación GPS?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps

Estoy obteniendo mi ubicación en un mapa usando **setMyLocationEnabled(true)** y la ubicación la muestra bien incluso si me muevo el punto azul que marca mi posición igual se mueve, pero no se como obtener las coordenadas de ese punto en el evento **onclick** de un botón.Es un código un poco largo por validaciones y cosas asi, incluyo lo correspondiente a la localización únicamente.

```
public class Mapa extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private ImageButton ubica;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapa_activity);

    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    if (status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No es posible iniciar mapa ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }    
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }     

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    UiSettings uiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
    uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);        

    //CODIGO AL HACER ONCLICK AL BOTON PARA ACEPTAR LA UBICACION Y OBTENER COORDENADAS
    ubica = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtn_aceptar);
    ubica.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    }); 
}
```

}

Y quiero en el evento onclick de mi boton que tengo obtener las coordenadas que de la ubicacion que me arroja mi mi app(es mi ibicacion actual, me la muestra con un punto azul).
¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Hola @Riu por favor agrega a tu pregunta el código que hayas intentado para que te puedan ayudar

Comment: Hola Riu en varias de tus preguntas no agregas código esencial para poder ayudarte, te sugiero revises [ask]. saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera, para demostrar que funciona muevo la camara a la posicion y agrego una marca.

```
FusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                lt = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                ln = String.valueOf((location.getLongitude()));
                LatLng Ubica = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(lt), Float.parseFloat(ln));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Ubica, 15));
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(lt), Float.parseFloat(ln))));
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Con esto deberias poder obtener tu latitud y longitud actualizada ya que tiene un listener que escucha por los valores una vez se cambian

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER);
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
    }
```

Usamos **PASSIVE_PROVIDER**

Desde la documentacion

> Este proveedor se puede usar para recibir pasivamente actualizaciones
>   de ubicación cuando otras aplicaciones o servicios lo solicitan sin
>   solicitarlas usted mismo. Este proveedor devolverá las ubicaciones
>   generadas por otros proveedores. Puede consultar el método
>   Location.getProvider () para determinar el origen de la actualización
>   de ubicación. Requiere el permiso
>   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, aunque si el GPS no está
>   habilitado, es posible que este proveedor solo devuelva correcciones
>   gruesas.

Doc: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#PASSIVE_PROVIDER

Comment: Al usar este método me trae la ultima ubicación conocida por el dispositivo, si no existe alguna me trae null,lo que no me funciona, por eso uso **mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)** porque ahí me manda mi ubicación en un mapa de maps usando la API pero no se como obtener la lat y long de ese punto en el mapa.

Comment: proba cambiar PASSIVE_PROVIDER POR GPS_PROVIDER y acordate de poner el permiso en el manifest de ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, y si no lo activa activalo vos desde configuracion - aplicaciones - tu app - permisos

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas recomendable para obtener tu localizacion es utilizar [Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current), el codigo resumido para lograr obtener la localizacion es este

```
LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    .getLastLocation()
    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            // Es raro que location sea null, pero mejor prevenir
            if (location != null) {
                // Aqui ya se donde estoy
            }
        }
    });
```